# How to automatically Import all subclasses of a root class in Python?

Tags: python, class, import

I'd like to know if it is possible to automatically import all subclasses of a class in python without writing import subclassxy for every subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **draft** example that can give you idea about what you want to do:

my_module.py

```
class RootClass(object):
    pass

class ChildClass(RootClass):
    pass
```

in another file.py

```
import sys

from my_module import RootClass

# Loop over all subclasses of RootClass.
for class_ in RootClass.__subclasses__():
    # from module import subclass.
    __import__(class_.__module__, globals(), locals(), [class_.__name__,])

    # Update the global namespace with the new class
    globals().update({class_.__name__:
                      getattr(sys.modules[class_.__module__], 
                              class_.__name__)})

print ChildClass
# OutPut : <class 'my_module.ChildClass'>
```

**PS: i don't advice you to do this !!!!**

Comment: This only works for subclasses that have already been imported, so it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Dan Ellis: it's not what i understand from the OP question i think he has already defined his subclasses and he want to import all of them knowing the base class without doing : import subclass1, subclass2 ...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, in general. The interpreter has no way of knowing whether or not a specific package defines a subclass of your class of interest. In principle, you can write a new package or module tomorrow defining a new subclass. It will now need to get imported. For the interpreter to keep track of all of this would be very burdensome.

You can construct a package that imports all subclasses of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a module that does the `import subclassxy` for every subclass (perhaps auto-generated) and `from module import *` it.

Answer (score 1):

This simply isn't possible, because Python has no way of knowing what subclasses exist until it has already seen them (at which point they'll be in the base class's **subclasses** attribute).

Why don't you tell us what you really want to achieve? That way, we can help you find a solution.

Comment: I want to be able to use subclasses without explicitly importing them everywhere, so that I can create a new subclass and use it somewhere else.